# error loading /scsi-qla.v01, fatal error:33

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am facing an issue, seems to be a rare one. No one has asked this question in any of the blog except for [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/VMWare/A_13595-HOW-TO-Fix-the-Error-loading-s-v00-Fatal-error-33-Inconsistent-data-in-the-VMware-vSphere-Hypervisor.html). One of my Esxi 5.1 host (not an actual server, but just a physical workstation acting as a server) was working till last week. Don't know what happened suddenly, it started showing the error as shown below:

[image]

I can't try installing a fresh Esxi on top of this, as there is so much of data residing on this. Are there anyone who faced this kind of issue? Any idea on how to solve this, besides the way [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/VMWare/A_13595-HOW-TO-Fix-the-Error-loading-s-v00-Fatal-error-33-Inconsistent-data-in-the-VMware-vSphere-Hypervisor.html) mentioned?

Comment: Is ESXi installed on a USB stick?

Comment: No. It is within the hard drive only.

Comment: Is the disk in a RAID configuration? Is the disk healthy?

Comment: The disk is healthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, my ESXi installation, became corrupted. I fixed it with the 3rd option.

Options:-

1. Fix as per this article

[HOW TO: Fix the Error loading /s.v00 Fatal error: 33 (Inconsistent data) in the VMware vSphere Hypervisor](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/VMWare/A_13595.html)

2. Recovery Mode - Press Shift and R at ESXi Boot, if you have ever upgraded ESXi, you will be able to rollback, to the previous version, and the  upgrade again.
3. Re-install ESXi. When re-installing, it will discover the older installation, and ask to upgrade or re-install, if you perform a re-install it will discover the existing VMFS partition, and ask you if you want to PRESERVE, select YES, and this will keep all your VMs, and then later at power on, just re-register the VMs with Inventory, which is browse the datastore, browse the folder, select the VMX file, Right Click and select Register VM

Comment: The second options worked well for me.
But after the rollback, all the VMs belonging to that host were listed on the inventory as unknown.. So before connecting the host back to the cluster, we removed all that VMs, connected back the host to the cluster then upgrade again.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, though the error message was "error loading /s.v00, fatal error:33"

I did have my server booting from VMware intallation on an external USB.

I downloaded and created a new installer from the latest version of 5.5, which happened to be update 2 and ran it.  I wasn't given a choice to re-install, only install and upgrade.

I chose upgrade and the process went through successfully and I was then able to boot my server normally.

Comment: Do you happen to remember if all the ESXi configuration remined intact, or you needed to reconfigure?

Comment: @OzEdri The upgrade process ran successfully and all of my configuration was intact.

Interestingly enough, I had a similar problem about 4 months ago on a 6.5 U2 server.  The VMWare installation was installed on a USB thumb drive that was plugged into the back of the server. After a power outage, the server could not come back up due to an error similar to OP's error. I ran the 6.5 U2 installer and chose upgrade and was able to successfully start up the server.  We tried to upgrade 6.5 update 3 recently and it failed.  We suspect a corrupt USB was the culprit.  We re-installed on a new USB.

Answer (score 1):

Also ran in to this problem on ESXi 7.0 (clueless as to what triggered it), as far as I know there has been no power outage. Anyway, 'upgrading' to ESXi 7.0 from a bootable usb did not fix the issue, however running a brand new install and re-registering my VM's did work.